Offsetting the Y-Axis From the Chart, in SwiftUI Charts
First, I have messed with SwiftUI for a long time, but this is the first time that I've actually started making a ship-quality app with it, so it's entirely possible (likely, even), that the answer is a simple one. I would still appreciate the help. I have very little pride, when learning new stuff.
The issue is that I'm setting up a Swift Chart, and it's a basic bar chart, showing the number of users in a system, splitting them between new users, and ones that have been established.
The output currently looks like so:

Which is great, but the problem that I'm having, right now, is this:

Note how little space there is, between the axis labels, and the chart edge.
I'd like to give it more breathing room, but I'm kind of stumped, as to the proper way to do that.
Thanks, in advance, for any help!
Here's the code for the chart section:
struct UserTypesChart: View {
    @State var data: [RCVST_DataProvider.RowPlottableData]
    
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox("SLUG-USER-TOTALS-CHART-TITLE".localizedVariant) {
        Chart(data) { inRowData in
                ForEach(inRowData.data, id: \.userType) { inUserTypeData in
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("SLUG-BAR-CHART-USER-TYPES-X".localizedVariant, inRowData.date),
                        y: .value("SLUG-BAR-CHART-USER-TYPES-Y".localizedVariant, inUserTypeData.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("SLUG-BAR-CHART-USER-TYPES-LEGEND".localizedVariant, inUserTypeData.userType.localizedString))
                }
            }
        }
        .chartYAxisLabel("Users", spacing: 12)
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(preset: .aligned, position: .leading) { _ in
                AxisGridLine()
                AxisValueLabel(anchor: .trailing)
            }
        }
        .chartXAxisLabel("Date", alignment: .bottom)
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(preset: .aligned, position: .bottom) { _ in
                AxisGridLine()
                AxisValueLabel()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

UPDATE AS OF OCTOBER 27, 2024:
Sweeper's answer was great, but the samples are taken every twelve hours, so that means the data is interpreted as two bars per day, with interesting results:

If I change it to .hour, I get even more interesting results:


Just a note adding an AxisTick() gives me the spacing I want, but it feels like a real kludge. I note that the gridlines seem to be narrower than the bars, so there seems to be an issue with the way the system is determining the sizes of the grids and the data.

I -sort of- fixed it, but it seems ... wrong. I added empty data arrays at the front and back of the data, and they seem to make the grid expand to the width of the bars. It looks like the bars are centered on their values, and the grid does not take the width of the bars into account.

Try using the horizontal spacing for the Y AxisValueLabel:
AxisValueLabel(horizontalSpacing: 20)

So in your example, something like this:
    .chartYAxis {
        AxisMarks(preset: .aligned, position: .leading) { _ in
            AxisGridLine()
            AxisValueLabel(horizontalSpacing: 20)
        }
    }


Thanks! This answers the question, but I'm still having issues with the value marks not lining up the way that I want. That's another issue, and one that I'm confident that I'll solve.

When plotting dates on a bar chart, always pass a unit: argument. In this case, each bar presumably represents a day, so you should do
BarMark(
    x: .value("X", inRowData.date, unit: .day), // HERE
    y: .value("Y", inUserTypeData.value)
)

This tells SwiftUI Charts that this is categorical data, and not continuous/numerical data. This helps the chart to lay out the chart in the way you expect, and adds some reasonable spacing between the axis and the marks.
This also gives the bars an appropriate width. Your current code should be emitting a warning telling you that the bar widths are not defined, and falling back to a default value.
If you want more spacing, you can pass a horizontalSpacing: argument like in Marcy's answer.

Well, this ... sort of ... works. I get more space, but the issue is that the samples are taken every twelve hours, so the bars are stacked. I'll update the question with the results. But this is really good information. Thanks!

@ChrisMarshall Oh I don't think unit: supports 12 hours unfortunately. I would convert the dates to String, which charts will also treat as "categorical data".

Just FYI. Even though the two answers I got gave me more useful information, and I am still greenchecking Marcy's answer, I ended up solving it by tweaking the domain argument of the chartXScale() adornment, like so:
    let minimumDate = data.first?.date.addingTimeInterval(-43200) ?? .now
    let maximumDate = data.last?.date.addingTimeInterval(43200) ?? .now

    •
    •
    •

    .chartXScale(domain: [minimumDate, maximumDate])

